# Why is שהחיינו called "ז" in P'sachim but "ח" in M'gila?

Tags: talmud-bavli, acronyms, maseches-pesachim, shehecheyanu, tractate-megillah

Why is the "שהחיינו" blessing abbreviated "ז" [in *Bavli P'sachim* 103](//www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.103a.4?lang=he) but "ח" [in *Bavli M'gila* 21](//www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.21b.5?lang=he)? I'd expect some consistency. And it's not like "ז" makes more sense, or "ח" less sense, in *P'sachim* than in *M'gila*.<sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>[1] In *P'sachim*, it's part of the initialisms "יקזנה" and "יקנהז", which as far as I can tell aren't words, whereas ["יקחנה" is one](//www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.20.7?lang=he). In *M'gila*, it's part of the initialism "מנח", which, yes, is a word, but if that's sufficient reason to pick "ח", then "ח" should be used in *P'sachim* too.</sup>

Comment: It's called ”Zman” on _Shabbat_ 23:1 which seems to agree with your reference in Pesachim

Comment: You give the greater part of the answer. In Pesachim too, the initial order isn't yaknahaz and there the Saying is a part of significant word

Comment: How else would we have pictures of hare hunting in the haggada?